# How to remove/disable a toolbar via python?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, gui

How do I remove or disable a toolbar e.g., Raster, programmatically using Python?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This one-liner will hide the raster toolbar from QGIS UI:

```
iface.rasterToolBar().setVisible(False)
```

Comment: To prevent your very brief Answer, irrespective of its accuracy, being deleted, I recommend that you edit it to provide more context about how it applies.  The minimum length of Answers (and Questions) here is normally about a paragraph.

Comment: Thanks a lot, works perfectly... (wonder why the labels and grass toolbars are not accessible in the same way?)

Answer (score 2):

That was [just discussed on the mailing list](http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/iface-missing-removeToolBar-td5130257.html):

```
#add toolbar 
tb = iface.addToolBar("My Toolbar") 
#remove toolbar 
del tb
```

I don't think you can disable the standard toolbars that way though. Maybe look into the customization functionality instead.

Comment: I think they want to remove a toolbar that is already there not one they have created.  Doing `setVisible` is enough to hide it.

Comment: Nathan, could you give an example e.g., hiding the Raster toolbar?