# How to close/remove QGIS welcome page (recent projects) for plugins?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

I have a python plugin that completely overwrites the GUI in QGIS. Now I'm trying to upgrade from the previous LTS version to 2.14, but the new feature (Recent Projects) shines through as displayed in the picture:

[image]

I tried all the answers mentioned [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/200035/how-to-close-remove-qgis-welcome-page-recent-projects-with-python) but none of them work. It looks like once I have the setting

```
[UI]
Customization\enabled=true
```

in my QGIS2.ini, then I can't get rid of the Recent Projects. Without UI customization this line here

```
projOpenAtLaunch=3
```

works and the Recent Projects is gone, but then I get the regular icons on top of everything and things look like this:

[image]

Any ideas how to solve it? Of course I could just add a non-transparent background to all my Qwidgets, but would prefer a solution that doesn't involve editing every UI file in Qt 4 Designer and then recompiling them.

Comment: Does your plugin load at startup?

Comment: Yeah. Everything works just fine except for seeing the "recent projects" in the background.

Comment: What about just hiding the toolbars from which those icons belong to as described in this post: [How to remove/disable a toolbar via python?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/90521/how-to-remove-disable-a-toolbar-via-python)

Comment: Everything is already disabled through the customization options, but when I remove  "Customization\enabled=true" then yes get rid of my the "recent projects" but also will remove all the UI customization.